# What does it mean for this exact sequence to split?

Tags: homological-algebra, topological-k-theory

On page 627 of [Vector Fields on Spheres](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/adams2.pdf), Adams writes:

> Our first concern is to show that the following exact sequence splits.
>   $$\mathbb Z = \tilde K_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R P^{4t}/\mathbb RP^{4t-1}) \xleftarrow{i} \tilde K_\mathbb R (\mathbb RP^n/\mathbb RP^{4t-1}) \xleftarrow{j} \tilde K_\mathbb R(\mathbb RP^n/\mathbb RP^{4t}).$$

I understand the definition of a split short exact sequence. However, I cannot find anything about a split sequence of length three. What does Adams mean by 'the following exact sequence splits'?

It appears that to prove this claim, Adams shows $j$ is a monomorphism and $i$ is an epimorphism. This implies that 
$$0 \leftarrow \mathbb Z = \tilde K_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R P^{4t}/\mathbb RP^{4t-1}) \xleftarrow{i} \tilde K_\mathbb R (\mathbb RP^n/\mathbb RP^{4t-1}) \xleftarrow{j} \tilde K_\mathbb R(\mathbb RP^n/\mathbb RP^{4t}) \leftarrow 0$$
is exact.

Comment: What does he do to prove it splits? You can deduce what he means by it if you see what he ends up proving.

Comment: @VictorZhang That $A\to B \to C$ is exact means $\rm{im}(A\to B) =\ker(B\to C)$, no more than that. Adams then goes on to prove $i$ is epi and $j$ is mono so the sequence above is short exact, but doesn't mention that $i$ or $j$ is split. Perhaps it is clear, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: ok, I elaborated on my comment a bit more. In this case, a definition of a split 3 term exact sequence could be taken to what I wrote in the second half. Then after he proves the epi and mono arrows, it reduced to the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence $A \to B \to C$ is a split exact sequence if it can be extended to a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ that splits.

As stated in the question, Adams shows that we can extend to an exact sequence
$$0 \leftarrow \mathbb Z = \tilde K_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R P^{4t}/\mathbb RP^{4t-1}) \xleftarrow{i} \tilde K_\mathbb R (\mathbb RP^n/\mathbb RP^{4t-1}) \xleftarrow{j} \tilde K_\mathbb R(\mathbb RP^n/\mathbb RP^{4t}) \leftarrow 0.$$

This sequence splits follows from the following easy lemma: any SES $0 \to A \xrightarrow{j} B \xrightarrow{i} \mathbb Z \to 0$ splits. Since $i$ is surjective, chose some $b \in B$ that maps to 1. Then define a section $s : \mathbb Z \to B$ by $s(1) = b$.